# How can I eliminate matched names from below Code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement

I am unable to understand how can I eliminate the record `Student Created inside Else 1st name` from the result.
As it was matched it should have been exited from the loop. Then why is it being printed in output?

#Code is ready to use

Code:

```
student_for_admission = [{"student_name": "1st name", "other_key": "other_val"},{"student_name": "johndoe", "student":"other_val"}]
Student_eligible = [{"name": "1st name", "other_key": "other_val1", "another_key": "another_val2"},{"name": "2nd name", "other_key": "other_val", "another_key": "another_val"},{"name": "3rd name", "other_key": "other_val", "another_key": "another_val"}]
student_created=0
student_updated=0
student_skipped=0
for student in student_for_admission:
    for eligible in Student_eligible:
        if eligible["name"] == student["student_name"]:
            # Matching student found
            print("Student updated " + eligible["name"])
            print("Skipped " + eligible["name"])
            student_skipped += 1
            print(student_skipped)
            print("Before break")
            break
            print("After break")
        else:
            # Create Student
            print("Student Created inside Else "+ eligible["name"])
            student_created += 1
```

Output:

```
Student updated 1st name
Skipped 1st name
1
Before break
Student Created inside Else 1st name
Student Created inside Else 2nd name
Student Created inside Else 3rd name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this solution, You need to add addition conditions as I mentioned in the below code.

```
student_for_admission = [{"student_name": "1st name", "other_key": "other_val"},
                         {"student_name": "johndoe", "student":"other_val"}]
Student_eligible = [{"name": "1st name", "other_key": "other_val1", "another_key": "another_val2"},
                    {"name": "2nd name", "other_key": "other_val", "another_key": "another_val"},
                    {"name": "3rd name", "other_key": "other_val", "another_key": "another_val"}]
student_created = 0
student_updated = 0
student_skipped = 0
students_visited = []
for student in student_for_admission:
    for eligible in Student_eligible:
        if eligible["name"] == student["student_name"]:
            # Matching student found
            print("Student updated " + eligible["name"])
            print("Skipped " + eligible["name"])
            student_skipped += 1
            print(student_skipped)
            print("Before break")
            students_visited.append(eligible['name'])
            break
        elif eligible['name'] not in students_visited:
            # Create Student
            print("Student Created inside Else " + eligible["name"])
            student_created += 1
```

I'm skipping those students which are visited/considered already.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

When it's checking for johndoe -> each and everytime if condition got false - that's why **1st name** got printed

Comment: I believe he's asking how to fix it

Comment: Thanks for the Clue, but yes is there any way I could make only Non -matched values to enter the Else. Have I placed it in a wrong way?

Comment: Non matched values of students for admission or students_eligible?

Answer (score 0):

You're right that the code exited from the loop, and it is the inner for loop. The code then moved onto the next student in student_for_admission.

The matched name is being printed in the output because you are printing the name from Student_eligible instead of from student, so it is printing out the ones that are eligible hence "matched name".

Try:

```
print("Student Created inside Else "+ student["student_name"])
```

in your else statement.